# I get undefined method 'when_present' in a ruby script, but it works in irb

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm using watir 4.0.2 and ruby 2.0.0:

Exact script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
@@ie = Watir::Browser.new
@@ie.goto("http://www.google.com")
@@ie.text_field(:name, 'q').when_present.set("bottlecaps")
```

Exact error message:

```
google_script.rb:8: undefined method 'when_present' for #<Watir::TextField:0x31eec60 located=false how=:name what="q"> <NoMethodError>
```

When I do this in a script, I get that error message, but when I do it in IRB, it behaves as I would expect.
Fairly similar questions posed on this site have been answered by doing something with permissions, but I don't see how that applies in this case.

Comment: give the error stack too

Comment: There isn't really an error stack, at least not that I know how to view. This is the output of the running of my script:  google_script.rb:8: undefined method 'when_present' for #<Watir::TextField:0x31eec60 located=false how=:name what="q"> <NoMethodError>

Comment: I ran the code seeing no issue.. which ruby version you do have?

Comment: my ruby version is 1.9.3p327

Comment: for me it is working... don't know what happened..

Comment: I just updated to ruby version 2.0.0p247 and I still get the same thing.

Comment: why don't you post the exact and complete script that doesn't work and the exact error message.  also make sure you check both the version of irb you're using as well as the version you're using when you run it as a script.  And which method exactly is undefined?  Help us help you.

Comment: @xaxxon - i've updated my original post to make it more clear, but i did post the exact and complete script, and the exact error message was in a comment.  i've added it to the original post.  i'm not sure how to tell the version i'm running in irb - if i type 'ruby -v' at the command prompt, it tells me 1.9.3.  then from that same command prompt, i type 'irb' but maybe it runs under a different version?

Comment: @atarihomestar  i hate @@ variables.  I Never use them and don't understand how they work.  Do you get the same problem if you don't use them?

Comment: How are you running the script? Is it possibly configured to use an older version of Watir? Since you have `require 'rubygems'`, it sounds like you are using and/or following something old.

Comment: @xaxxon - i got rid of the class variables (@@) and i still get the same error.

Comment: @Justin Ko - I'm doing this at a windows command prompt.  I'm just typing the name of the file - google_script.rb Oh, and I tried it without the require 'rubygems' line and I still get the error.

Comment: Just to make sure that the script is pulling the right gems, try adding `puts Gem.loaded_specs["watir"].version` after the require statements. Also check the loaded gem for `watir-classic` and `watir-webdriver`.

Comment: @JustinKo - I think you're onto something.  It says that my watir version is 1.6.5, even though when I do a 'gem list' from the command prompt, I get 'Watir (4.0.2 x86-ming32, 2.0.4)' Any ideas?

Comment: How many versions of Ruby do you have installed? Are you using something like RVM to have multiple versions?

Comment: @JustinKo - well, that was it.  I had a few versions of ruby on my machine.  I got rid of everything and reinstalled my gems, and then it said that i had Watir 4.0.2 loaded, and then my script worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem was that the script was loading an older version of the watir gem (v1.6.5), while IRB was loading the latest watir gem (v4.0.2).

The gem loaded can be seen by using:

```
puts Gem.loaded_specs["watir"].version
```

The solution was to uninstall all of the gems and reinstall just the current gems.